# Count in multi-dimensional array

Tags: ios, objective-c

How would you count this array?

```
NSArray *sortThisArray = @[@{@"numbers":@[@"One",@"Two"]},
                               @{@"numbers":@[@"Two",@"One"]},
                               @{@"numbers":@[@"One",@"Two",@"Three"]},
                               @{@"numbers":@[@"One",@"Two",@"Three"]},
                               @{@"numbers":@[@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four"]},
                               ];
```

The desired result would then be:

```
NSArray *sortedArray =   @[@{@"numbers":@[@"One",@"Two"],
                             @"occures":@(2)},

                             @{@"numbers":@[@"One",@"Two",@"Three"],
                             @"occures":@(2)},

                             @{@"numbers":@[@"One",@"Two",@"Three",@"Four"],
                             @"occures":@(1)},
                          ];
```

I've tried using `NSCountedSet` and `countForObject`, but the results are inaccurate. It seems to only count the arrays that are exactly the same. In other words, the array with `@[@"Two",@"One"]` gets ignored because its not 100% equal to `@[@"One",@"Two"]`, even though they have the same objects and same count.

Answer (score 0):

This should work. You have to have a consistent way to compare your arrays (either sorting like in this example or by moving the NSArray to NSSet).

```
NSMutableDictionary<NSArray<NSString *> *, NSNumber *> *valueCount = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
for (NSDictionary<NSString *, NSArray<NSString *> *> *value in sortThisArray) {
    NSArray<NSString *> *numberStrings = [value[@"numbers"] sortedArrayUsingSelector:@selector(compare:)];
    valueCount[numberStrings] = @(valueCount[numberStrings].integerValue + 1);
}

NSMutableArray *sortedArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithCapacity:valueCount.count];
for (NSArray<NSString *> *key in valueCount) {
    [sortedArray addObject:@{@"numbers": key, @"occures": valueCount[key]}];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

May be something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *mArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:sortThisArray];
NSMutableArray *result = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];


while ([mArray count]) {
    NSDictionary *obj = [mArray firstObject];
    int count = 1;
    for (int i=1; i<[mArray count]; i++) {
        NSDictionary *sObj = [mArray objectAtIndex:i];
        if ([[sObj objectForKey:@"numbers"] count] == [[obj objectForKey:@"numbers"] count]) {
            BOOL increase = YES;
            for (int j=0; j<[[obj objectForKey:@"numbers"] count]; j++) {
                if (![[sObj objectForKey:@"numbers"] containsObject:[[obj objectForKey:@"numbers"] objectAtIndex:j]]) {
                    increase = NO;
                }
            }
            if (increase) {
                count++;
                [mArray removeObjectAtIndex:i];
            }
        }
    }
    [mArray removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    [result addObject:@{@"numbers":obj, @"occurrs":[NSNumber numberWithInteger:count]}];
}
```

*Code is not tested

Comment: Tried it out, doesn't seem to work... Still getting duplicates in result array